# Flash drive file system isn't recognized

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, usb, filesystem, usb-drive

I recently got this credit/business-card shaped USB flash drive.
In windows 7 it's recognized fine, after some drivers are automatically installed (without user interaction) once it's plugged-in.

**In Ubuntu 13.04 all I can see in gparted is that the file system on the device is "unknown" and it also won't appear in Nautilus' device list (on the left panel).**

When I ran this command:

```
sudo file -Ls /dev/sdb
```

that's what I got:

```
/dev/sdb: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0xc, starthead 0, startsector 32, 7826656 sectors, extended partition table (last)\011, code offset 0x0
```

Edit - also, when running this:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
```

That's what I got:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 4007 MB, 4007264256 bytes
230 heads, 63 sectors/track, 540 cylinders, total 7826688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              32     7826687     3913328    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Any ideas? 
(I'd rather not format it with Ubuntu because I'm afraid it might make the situation worse)

Comment: If it took a special driver for it to be recognized in Windows, it might not be usable in Linux, at least not as-is. You might learn more by typing `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1`, though; that will return a report on the basic contents of the single partition on the drive (its filesystem type, for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved by simply running this command:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Not sure why it won't auto-mount or show in Nautilus' side-bar like other flash drives, but from the terminal it works fine this way (Thanks to Nati)